# SQL Server RDS master user disabled

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds

I've inherited a SQL Server Web Edition RDS instance from another firm whereby they took a snapshot and then shared it with our firm's RDS account.

After reinstating the instance under our account, I wanted to set up [native backups](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/native-backup-rds-sql-server/) but ran in to permissions issues when running the msdb.dbo.rds_backup_database command:

```
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'rds_backup_database', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.
```

Believing this was due to permissions issues on the account that was given to me, I reset the used the "New master password" functionality within the RDS console to reset the master password. After I was notified that succeeded, I attempted to login but got a login failed error.

In looking at the results from the following query, `select * from master.sys.server_principals` I can see that the master login is disabled.

When running the following query,

```
select suser_sname(owner_sid) as 'Owner', state_desc, *
from sys.databases
```

I can see that all the databases were created with the master account.

How would I enable the master user's login in this case or does anyone know of a workaround?

Thanks,

-Ben

Comment: Have you tried using the new-master-password in RDS again?

Comment: Yes but I get a login failed message and in the RDS error log window I see the following error, "An error occurred while evaluating the password.", which I believe is because the account is disabled.